# Is stream() method lazy? If lazy then can this method itself considered intermediate as it is for returning a stream?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

```
List<Item> applePhones = list.stream()
            .filter((item) -> item.getCompany().equalsIgnoreCase("Apple"))
            .filter((item) -> item.getDevice().equalsIgnoreCase("Phone"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here these filter operations are intermediate and collect is terminal then what the stream call is?

Comment: It creates a stream. Terms like "intermediate" and "terminal" only make sense when you are calling a method on a `Stream`, but you are not calling `stream()` on a `Stream`, so it doesn't really have a special classification.

Comment: A Stream has to come from somewhere, `stream()` is that somewhere, it creates the stream object, it _is_ lazy in a sense that it does not immediately take all the objects from the list and stores them internally.

Comment: Note that the paranthesis around `item` are obsolete. So `item -> ...` instead of `(item) -> ...` works the same. You only need them if you have no arguments or more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is `stream()` as you used it, is not a `Stream` method (It's `Collection.stream`). And that means that the *intermediate vs terminal* or *lazy vs eager* distinctions of stream methods/operations are irrelevant.

`List.stream` in this case represents the source of the stream. Having a stream object, you then invoke intermediate and/or terminal operations on it (`filter` and `collect` in your example). That's a simple way to put it to avoid getting philosophical.

The way I understand it (probably oversimplified):

- `streamObject.operation()` -> `Stream`: intermediate/lazy stream operation (`stream.filter()`, `stream.map()`, etc.)
- `streamObject.operation()` -> something else or void: terminal stream operation (`stream.collect()`, `stream.count()`, etc.)
- `somethingElse.stream()` -> `Stream`: source (I don't think *source* is "the name" for this *stream factory/creator* concept, although that's what the [`java.util.stream` package docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) refer to this as, as far as I can see) - (`list.stream()`, `Arrays.stream()`, `Stream.of()`, `optional.stream()`, `reader.lines()`, etc.)

Comment: But stream producing methods like the `stream()` method of collections also have a categorization. They may be “immutable”, “concurrent”, or “late binding”.